# Rails displays hash at the end of a list

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, list, alphabetical

I'm running Rails 3.2.11. I have an article model:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :content, :name
end
```

My controller (index action) is:

class ArticlesController < ApplicationController

```
  def index
    @grouped = {}
    Article.all.each do |article|
      letter = article.name.slice(0,1)
      @grouped[letter] ||= []
      @grouped[letter] << article
    end
  end
```

This creates an alphabetical list of all article names for an overview page. The index.html.haml is:

```
%p
  %ul
    - @grouped.keys.sort.each do |letter|
      %h1
        = letter
      %ul
        = @grouped[letter].each do |article|
          %li
            = link_to article.name, article
```

Now I got a list of all article names, sorted by letter, but at the end of all articles of a certain letter here is a hash displaying all the data:

```
A

- Albert
- Altman
- Armstrong
[#<Article id: 3, name: "Albert", content: "dpio osahu psauhd asuhd psauh piuh asuhd uh isah iu...", created_at: "2013-01-11 11:51:30", updated_at: "2013-01-11 11:51:30">, #<Article id: 6, name: "Altman", content: "aosdi asoijd poisajpo isajdpoia sjdpoia jsapoij sap...", created_at: "2013-01-11 12:36:10", updated_at: "2013-01-11 12:36:10">, #<Article id: 7, name: "Armstrong", content: "osfduhsdo sdpiuh dspiufh sdpioufhsdioufh sdpiufh sd...", created_at: "2013-01-11 12:42:08", updated_at: "2013-01-11 12:42:08">]
```

How can I get rid of the final hash?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
= @grouped[letter].each do |article|
```

replace that line with this

```
- @grouped[letter].each do |article|
```

`each` returns a collection it iterated. You don't need to print that, you already printed all individual elements.